# Reflection - Call constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I read type from loaded assemblies for example:

```
var someType = loadedAssemblies
            .Where(a => a != null && a.FullName.StartsWith("MY."))
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray()[0];
```

If counstructor has parameters, i can read them:

```
ParameterInfo[] parameters = classType.GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters();
```

I would like to call constructor with default parameter values or if parameter is enum, with first enum value.
If there is only one parameter and it is enum, it works like this:

```
object curObject = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { parameters[0].ParameterType.GetEnumValues().GetValue(0) });
```

How can I do this when there are more parameters?
I need to create object to read the property:

```
var propertyInfo = someType.GetProperty("EntityType");
string entityType = propertyInfo.GetValue(curObject, null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can create your own Factory, and write a method, that checks constructors for the type and runs first parameterized ctor with its default values:

```
public static class MyFactory
{
    public static T MyCreateInstance<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return (T) MyCreateInstance(typeof (T));
    }

    public static object MyCreateInstance(Type type)
    {
        var parametrizedCtor = type
            .GetConstructors()
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetParameters().Length > 0);

        return parametrizedCtor != null
            ? parametrizedCtor.Invoke
                (parametrizedCtor.GetParameters()
                    .Select(p =>
                        p.HasDefaultValue? p.DefaultValue :
                        p.ParameterType.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType) == null
                            ? Activator.CreateInstance(p.ParameterType)
                            : null
                    ).ToArray()
                )
            : Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

And then use this method:

```
var classType = loadedAssemblies
            .Where(a => a != null && a.FullName.StartsWith("MY."))
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray()[0];

var curObject = MyFactory.MyCreateInstance(classType);

// This will return an array of values

object[] values = classType
                 .GetFields()
                 .Select(f => f.GetValue(curObject))
                 .ToArray();
```

P.S.
Here is a [DotNet fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NejxRD).

> Update:

The code is changed according to scenario you work with. Now we have two methods,
one returns object, and another one that can convert it to type T.

I've also updated the DotnetFiddle, please check it.

Comment: Hi Fabjan, thanks for this solution. There is one problem.
I have only classType, which i read at runtime. I don't know for the object(class) name at compile time. Your code: var curObject = MyFactory.MyCreateInstance<object>(classType); doesn't work with object keyword.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well as code example on DotNetfiddle

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect. Do you know the difference between constructor.Invoke vs Activator.CreateInstance?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a helper method to get default value of a type:

```
private static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsEnum) return type.GetEnumValues().GetValue(0);
    if (type.IsValueType) return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return null;
}
```

Then, you can get default values of the parameters:

```
var parameters = constructor.GetParameters()
                            .Select(p => GetDefaultValue(p.ParameterType))
                            .ToArray();
```

And invoke the `ConstructorInfo` to get the instance:

```
var obj = constructor.Invoke(parameters);
```

---

If the constructor's parameters have default values and you want to use them, you can do something like this:

```
var parameters = constructor
    .GetParameters()
    .Select(p => p.HasDefaultValue ? p.RawDefaultValue : GetDefaultValue(p.ParameterType))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Arturo, what is the difference of constructor.Invoke vs Activator.CreateInstance? Can you do the same with Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: @Simon: `Constructor.Invoke` directly invoke that constructor. `Activator.CreateInstance` creates an instance finding the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.