# Dynamically creating and calling a class using Reflection in a console application

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have some problems about this section in C# language.

So I'm trying to do something like revealing reflection of this class and it's methods.

```
class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Shifts{ get; set; }


    public Car(string name, int shifts)
    {
        Name = name;
        Shifts = shifts;
    }

    public string GetCarInfo()
    {
        return "Car " + Name + " has number of shifts: " + Shifts;
    }

}
```

So I have this class Car, and this method GetCarInfo(), now, I'm trying to:
Dynamically create instance of this class Car, and dynamically calling a method GetCarInfo(), I would like to show result in console, but I can't when I run it it shows build errors. The application break every time.

### Edit

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60SlE.png)

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean with "dynamically create instance", "dynamically calling a method", and so on..? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You mean something like this? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915110/reflection-call-constructor-with-parameters

Comment: @n0idea I'll post now a build errors and code so you could maybe better understand.. Wait a second please.

Comment: @BugCatcherJoe I'm new to this, but I think it is not the same.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Done.

Comment: @xVenum.dll Hi, i created a console application with an example, i think this is what you want.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim I'll try this, moment please.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim Same error, "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type'"

Comment: @xVenum.dll As I said in the comment on the code, be careful with the namespace, you need the full namespace of the class to get the type, as I showed in the example Type.GetType("ConsoltedeTEstes.Car");

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim My mistake again.. It works,  but it isn't showing anything is this okay?

Comment: @xVenum.dll your method GetCarInfo returns a string, so you must do a Console.WriteLine(returnOfMethd), please debug the method and see if var returnOfMethod = method.Invoke(dinamycCar, new string[0]); the varible returnOfMethod  has the string you want

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim Thanks, it works. I'm trying this for days..

Comment: You are welcome, please, note that when a function returns a string, it doesnt necessarily do anything, you must work with the string you get, please feel free to ask any doubts you have

Answer (score 2):

Here's a example

```
namespace ConsoltedeTEstes
  {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Get the type of the car, be careful with the full name of class
        Type t = Type.GetType("ConsoltedeTEstes.Car");

        //Create a new object passing the parameters
        var dynamicCar = Activator.CreateInstance(t, "User", 2);

        //Get the method you want
        var method = ((object)dynamicCar).GetType().GetMethod("GetCarInfo");

        //Get the value of the method
        var returnOfMethod = method.Invoke(dynamicCar, new string[0]);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Shifts { get; set; }


    public Car(string name, int shifts)
    {
        Name = name;
        Shifts = shifts;
    }

    public string GetCarInfo()
    {
        return "Car " + Name + " has number of shifts: " + Shifts;
    }

}


}
```