# Creating an EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null); under MethodInfo and calling it

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Ive been working on an alternative way to invoke entrypoint, But the problem is; it keeps telling me its a non-static method and just wont work.

Any help?

I've tried creating a new instance.
I've tried every kind of BindingFlags.

```
MethodInfo addMethod = entry.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object[]) });
object o = ((Assembly)assembly).CreateInstance(entry.Name); 
addMethod.Invoke(o, new Type[] { null, null });
```

**Error 1**
[image: Error 1]

**Error 2**
[image: Error 2]

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673927/dynamic-creating-and-calling-an-class-using-reflection-console-application/54674255#54674255) link, maybe it could help you

Comment: You are invoking the method on `o`, but getting a method on `entry`. Clearly the types don't match. Please describe, what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `Non-static method requires a target` just means you need to have an instance of the object to pass in to the Invoke.  Notice the in the answer @JoãoPauloAmorim linked to, the `Activator.CreateInstance()` call that creates does this.

Comment: @Gus I've tried that also, let me show you what i get. (I still get the same error)

Comment: Did you try passing the "entry" object into the invoke method. The error says that the method is not static, so you need to invoke it on an object, not just the class.